# How to store multiple rows at a same time in php with for each loop?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am using below code to store data in table.

```
public function insert_pay_slip_data($data,$com_name)
    {

        $con = $this->__construct();
        $data = explode(',', $data[0]);
        foreach ($data as $value) 
            {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `pay_slips`(`paye_id`, `trade_id`, `inv_pdf`, `created_date`, 
                `created_by`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '".$com_name."','".$value."',NOW(),'".$_SESSION['email']."')";
                $execute = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                return $execute;
            }
    }
```

On print_r($data) i am getting all files that i am uploading from view:

```
Array ( [0] => 6650f7.pdf [1] => 34a3f.pdf [2] => 169512017.pdf )
```

> I am getting this array in $data. So my concern is to store each file
>   in different row with different primary keys.

But In for each loop $data only shows last uploaded file and in db only last file is inserted. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: In your foreach loop you have a return that will exit the function on the first iteration. Also, why do you call the constructor of your class to get a sql connexion ?

Comment: What do you mean by _"In for each loop $data only shows last uploaded file"_?

Comment: Please read http://bobby-tables.com/ and enlighten yourself as to why building parameterised SQL queries by concatenating strings is a bad idea

Answer (score 2):

```
return $execute;
```

Are you aware that this exits the function after one row has been inserted? This terminates the loop.

Read http://php.net/return for documentation about the `return` statement in PHP.

---

This is not related to your problem of ending the loop early, but your code is insecure, it's vulnerable to **SQL injection**.

You should use query parameters instead of concatenating variables into your SQL statement. Read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for more details on SQL injection.

Using query parameters is more secure and is actually *easier* to write the code than all those `'".$value."'` sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in single short like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `pay_slips`(`paye_id`, `trade_id`, `inv_pdf`, `created_date`, `created_by`) VALUES";
$i = 0;
foreach ($data as $value)
{
    if($i>0) {
        $sql .=",(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '".$com_name."','".$value."',NOW(),'".$_SESSION['email']."')"; 
    } else {
        $sql .="(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '".$com_name."','".$value."',NOW(),'".$_SESSION['email']."')";
    }
} 
$execute = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
return $execute;
```